# python insert 3d dictionary to sqlite3

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I have a 3d dictionary and want to insert the data into sqlite3

I know how to insert 1d data but I haven't tried to insert 2d or 3d data and I don't know how to do it.

```
data = {'username': {'classes': {'closedclasses': {'classCode5': {'code': 'phys111',
                                                       'term': 'fall'}},
                      'openclasses': {'classCode1': {'code': 'art123',
                                                     'term': 'Fall'},
                                      'classCode2': {'code': 'art111',
                                                     'term': 'spring'}}},
          'name': {'firstName': 'aaaa', 'lastName': 'bbbb'}}}
```

The data will have more than one username and each username has a different amount of data for openclasses and closeedclasses. How can I store all the data so that in the future I can call them like this:

```
data[username]["openclasses"]["classCode2"]["code"]

data[username]["name"]["firstName"]
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't seem to be very well structured. How exactly you want to store it in a database depends on how normalized you want it to be. You could simply flatten it and insert it into one table, or you could goto the other extreme and have tables for countries, states and provinces. It really depends on what you want to do with the data

Comment: @e4c5 I am sorry my example was not correct, I have updated the question, thank you

Comment: I think your best bet will be to use multiple tables, but how exactly to go about that and then map that back to your python object hierarchy is probably too broad for this forum.

Comment: If you're simply storing the values for use later the best bet is probably seralizing the data - `json.dumps` before inserting, then `json.loads` when retrieving, for example.

Comment: @IanMcLaird even if I used multiple tables I cannot retrieve the classes because some username will have different amount of open and closed classes ( here is my problem )

Comment: @g.d.d.c first I need to store them into a sqlite so I can call them later, I can create columns for name and its data, and for username I can create 2 columns for open and closed classes BUT how to store their data?! for open and closed they have have different amount of classes and it's different from each username

Comment: I have an idea to store them, for example create a column for openclasses then store its data like this art123-fall%art111-spring then when I call them I do split using % then split each list with "-", but I got another problem how can I delete a classes from the database?! if I have art111-fall%art222-fall%art333-fall then I finished my work from art222-fall how can I delete this to make the value become art111-fall%art333-fall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to have table name users as follows

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

Then a table for classes

```
id
class_code
term
status   # open or closed
```

As already mentioned in the comments, your json isn't really well structured. `classCode5`, `classCode2` etc should really only be `classCode` whatever code you write you are going to have your work cut out fetching this information from the JSON.

Last but not least, you need a table to link the users and the classes.

```
 id
 user_id
 class_id
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I can get red of openclasses but I still need the closedclasses, I will create columns for first_name, last_name, username but the class code and terms will have 2d data

Comment: The structure i have given does not force you to get rid of anything. The classes table supports both open and closed classes. Note the status field. This will be true for open, and false for closed. Or you can make it a text field and insert either 'open' or 'closed' into it.

Comment: @user2564147, using this solution, you do not need to get rid of openclasses.  Open and closed classes are stored together in a single table.  You'll need to use SQL to get the ones you want populated into your object.